# Zend headTitle() encoding issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, encoding

I have a problem with Zends headTitle command and special characters, mainly Swedish characters (åäö). In my layout i have specified a header like this:

> $this->headTitle('Title - ','PREPEND');

In my controllers I then specify different subtitles like this:

> $this->view->headTitle = "Subtitle";

This works fine so long as all characters are ASCII but as soons as I put anything else in the subtitle the Title of my page goes from "Title - Subtitle" to "URI" ergo the title becomes "http://mydoman.se/controller/action/"

The encoding for the page is set by zend trough

> $this->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');

the encoding is correctly set according to the browser and when I review the html output.
The encoding of all files are ISO-8859-1, and the same goes for my database. All special chars I've ever tried works in the rest of the site, so why doesn't it work in the title??

Any help would be very appreciated. (Note, it did work with encoding UTF-8, but for various reasons I must use ISO-8859-1 in the live environment for now)

Comment: It is your problem. Because you chose `ISO-8859-1`. If you will use UTF-8, all will be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set encoding in:

- view resource (e.g. in `application.ini`)
- view script (meta tag)
- send appriopriate HTTP header

Comment: Thanks a million. The line: resources.view.encoding                         ="ISO-8859-1" in my application.ini solved the problem